# Stopping spring-batch-application at a method joinpoint when method is defined in an abstract class

Tags: java, spring-batch, interceptor

Updated content:
For some system tests on batch applications in my project I want to influence the behavior of job steps from within the test class. For this purpose I attach a 'MethodInterceptor' to any step beans e.g. an exception-thrower interceptor to the `writer` bean.

In my case, the writer class `Xyzwriter` is extending an abstract class that implements `ItemWriter`.

```
public abstract class Abstractwriter implements ItemWriter {
...
@override 
public void write(){
//writing
}


public class Xyzwriter extends Abstractwriter {

   public void someMethod(){
    //dowhat
   }

}
```

Note that the `write` method is only overriden inside the abstract class.

Now I want to stop the batch exactly on the `write` method. So I have to pass a methodinterceptor to the writerbean.
For this, I defined a BeanPostProcessor, and inside the configuration class I attach a Methodinterceptor to the writer bean for its write method:

```
myBeanPostProcessor.getMap().put("Xyzwriter", dangerousWriterInterceptor);
```

Where:

```
public class MyBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

private Map<String , MyInterceptoredBeanType> map = new HashMap<>();

  @Override
  public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String intercepedBeanName) throws BeansException {

       if ( map.get(intercepedBeanName) != null ){
         return map.get(intercepedBeanName);
       }
       return bean;
  }
}
```

Inside the test after spring context is loaded, I turn on/off the exception-throwing-bahvior of the bean `dangerousWriterInterceptor`, and start the job.

But, this way, I get the Error: 'NoSuchMethodException'.
Which is clear, since `write` is only defined in the abstract class!

Second try: I override the `write` method in the `XYZwriter` like

```
public class XYZwriter extends Abstractwriter {

   @Override
   public void write(){ 
      super.write(args);
   }

}
```

In this case  get the Error:

```
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: found more than one method on target class[XYZwriter$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1052d06a] with the annotation type [BeforeStep].
```

What can I do to intercept the write method using my `BeanBosProcessor`?

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to achieve without referring to Spring Batch? From the title you seem to want to stop a job from the item writer. Is that what you are trying to do? Can you describe your use case for that?

Comment: In our project we have divers kind of spring batch applications with large amount of data beeing processed. In order to measure the restartability behavior of the batches in case of system failures such as server connection issues I was tasked with developing an appropriate concept. I plan to stop the batch by throwing an exception while invoking 'read', 'write' or 'process' methods, and then restarting the abborted job. –

Comment: Why not just throwing an exception from the writer to fail the job and then restart it? Why do you need a bean post processor for that?

Comment: Using the BeanPostProcessor I  do not need to change a running code since the Beanpostprocessor is configured and used only in test class.